# ReferenceError: nokia is not defined. Getting this error only in Mozilla Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla, nokia

I am using nokia maps in my application. The map works perfectly fine in Chrome and IE. But it is not working in Mozilla Firefox browser.

The version of mozilla I am using is **51.0.1 (32-bit)**

I tried to debug in the browser. If I add watch expression for nokia, Then also it is throwing the same error.

**ReferenceError: nokia is not defined.**

I am currently using the below URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/se/2.5.3/jsl.js?with=all"></script>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem and solution.

In chrome and IE it is working fine because, it is allowing the content to load though the website does not support HTTPS.

But, In Mozilla Firefox, It is not loading the content at all.

I modified the URL with only HTTP, not with HTTPS.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://js.cit.api.here.com/se/2.5.3/jsl.js?with=all"></script>
```